# Are there any downsides to installing packages manually on GitHub runners?

Tags: automation, continuous-integration, github-actions, github-actions-runners

I have been trying workflows on GitHub and wanted to set one up to run skaffold commands. I need minikube, helm and skaffold installed.

Most examples that I have checked out run other actions, such as [github-action-skaffold](https://github.com/hiberbee/github-action-skaffold) , which after trying it out, doesn't have support for all skaffold commands and options and it has a bug when running `skaffold test`. I tried manually installing it on `ubuntu-20-04`, like so:

```
- name: Install Skaffold
  run: |
    curl -Lo skaffold https://storage.googleapis.com/skaffold/releases/latest/skaffold-linux-amd64 && \
    sudo install skaffold /usr/local/bin/

- name: Build
  run: skaffold build
```

And everything is working fine. Is there anything that I am missing out on when doing this? Using the action would be a step less, as it can both install skaffold and run a command, but that is not a deal breaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, your method is fine.
As far as you have two lines of code with a meaningful name, your CI code is OK.
(Probably make sense to fix Skaffold version instead of using 'latest').